# Encountering problem checking the rotation value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a minigame where I have the picture below, sliced into 32 pieces.

[image]

On Play/Start all the pieces are rotated randomly in multiplications of 90. From 0 -> [90,180,270].
The goal of the game is to rotate all the pieces to 0 Z-Axis Rotation, then a UI will pop up stating that you win.

The game plays as I expected it to, up to the point of the last 1-3 pieces, where even their rotation is not 0, the UI triggers and the game ends.
Example below, see piece top-right above the UI text.
[image]
**GameControllerSlice Script**

```
    public class GameControllerSlice : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] PicturePieces;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject winText;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject winTextBackground;

    public static bool youWin = false;
    private readonly int[] randomZ = new int[] {90, 180, 270};
    private int randomIndex;

    void Start()
    {
        Randomizer();
        winText.SetActive(false);
        winTextBackground.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        RotationCheck();
    }

    //Randomizes the rotation of the Z-axis value.
    private void Randomizer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            randomIndex = Random.Range(1, randomZ.Length - 1);
            PicturePieces[i].transform.Rotate(0, 0, randomZ[randomIndex]);
        }
    }

    //Checks if the rotation of each pieces is 0.
    private void RotationCheck()
    {
        if (Pictures.All(pic => (int) pic.transform.rotation.z == 0f))
        {
            youWin = true;
            winText.SetActive(true);
            winTextBackground.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

On each individual piece I have a the script with the simple code below.
**TouchRotate Script**

```
public class TouchRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
     if (!GameControllerSlice.youWin)
     {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, -90);
     }
    }
}
```

I've spend the past 3 days doing trial & error, with no success.
Also tried a different approach shown below, but that gave me a whole other problem, because I can't read/update the index properly from **TouchRotate** back into the **GameControllerSlice** script.
Excuse some leftover comments I was trying different things.

```
public class GameControllerSlice : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] PicturePieces;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject winText;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject winTextBackground;

    public static bool youWin = false;
    public static int[] RandomizedPics = new int[32];
    private readonly int[] randomZ = new int[] {0, 90, 180, 270};
    private int randomIndex;

    void Start()
    {
        FillRandomList();
        Randomizer();
        winText.SetActive(false);
        winTextBackground.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        RotationCheck();
    }

    public void FillRandomList()
    {
        foreach (int i in RandomizedPics)
        {
            RandomizedPics[i] = randomZ[0];
            // Debug.Log("Value " + RandomizedPics[i]);
        }
    }

    //Randomizes the rotation of the Z-axis value.
    private void Randomizer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            randomIndex = Random.Range(1, randomZ.Length - 1);
            PicturePieces[i].transform.Rotate(0, 0, randomZ[randomIndex]);
            RandomizedPics[i] = randomIndex;
        }
    }

    //Checks if the rotation of each pieces is 0.
    private void RotationCheck()
    {
        for (int i =0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            if (RandomizedPics[i] != 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Picture " + PicturePieces[i] + "value " + RandomizedPics[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class TouchRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        //if (!GameControllerSlice.youWin)
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, -90);
        //Debug.Log("Clicked Pic " + name + "with value " + System.Array.IndexOf(gameController.Pictures, this));
        // Debug.Log(System.Array.IndexOf(gameController.Picturesgo, this.transform.gameObject));
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help or pointers to the right direction for either approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all due to [floating point imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) you **never** want to rely on `==`/`!=` for `float` values!

You rather want to check within a certain range

```
if(Mathf.Abs(x - 0f) <= threshold)
```

e.g. using [`Mathf.Aproximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(x, 0f))
```

which basically equals using

```
if(Mathf.Abs(x - 0f) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
```

where [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) is the smallest value two floats can differ.

---

And then [`Transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) which doesn't have 3 but 4 components `x,y,z,w` and they all move in ranges `-1` to `1`.

**Never** access/set those values directly unless you know exactly what you are doing.

```
(int) pic.transform.rotation.z
```

is not what you want to check for.

---

Either check on the [`Transform.localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) - I would use local space since [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) is also applied in local space by default which might just be an additional issue in your case since you check the global rotation

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(pic.transform.localEulerAngles.z, 0))
```

or in general to not have to deal with rotations and Euler angles issues I usually would rather just go vector math wise and use this little "trick"

```
if(pic.transform.up == Vector3.up)
```

which already uses a reduced precision of [`0.00001`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html). This is way less error prone and simply compares the two up vectors.

Or if you want a little less precision e.g. if later the user can actually rotate these freely I would go for [`Vector3.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html)

```
if(Vector3.Angle(pic.transform.up, Vector3.up) <= thresholdAngle)
```

---

Oh and a final note:

```
randomIndex = Random.Range(1, randomZ.Length - 1);
```

will always return `1` -> `180`.

Arrays are indexed 0-based and for `int` the `Random.Range` returns values between `min` and `max - 1`.

You probably rather wanted

```
randomIndex = Random.Range(0, randomZ.Length);
```

in order to pick any of the available options ;)

Comment: WoW, you are a life saver!
The Vector3.up worked perfectly.
I had figured out that I should not mess with Quaternions and float checks, that's why I tried the index approach, but in the end I just made a bigger mess for myself.
Thank you for your detailed explanation.
Lesson learned!

Comment: @ChristosFotos just added a little update at the very bottom ;)

Comment: Saw it right after, I edited my response. Thanks for that one too, I missed it.
Once again thanks for the quick, detailed and comprehensive response. Learned a lot.